# copy data from table to another without matching the primary number

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables:

Table1 has the following columns (id, username, email).

Table2 has the following columns (id, name, username, email, password, registerDate, activation)

How can I copy all the data from Table1 to Table2?

Note: the id numbers of each row in Table1 NOT matching the id numbers in Table2. I just need to move the data from Table1 to Table2 as the rest columns in Table2 not necessary for me.

Comment: you want to replace data or just append in the tb2?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: @urfusion I want just append in Table2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single INSERT...SELECT can do that:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (`username`, `email`) (SELECT `username`, `email` FROM table1)
```

This will append all records from `table1` into `table2`.

Comment: It shows me this wrong message: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 1):

There are two things

1. replace data

Which can't possible because you do not have same `ids` is both table.

2. append data

for append data in `tb2`. You need to first select the data from `tb1` and fire `insert` query on `tb2`

```
select * from tb1
```

fetch results. apply loop and insert query inside loop.

```
insert into tb2 (fields) values();
```

Comment: I did that for several times but the message is #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: you might be passing more then you want to insert the value